# How to run a function in service when click on actionClick of Notification?

Tags: android

I have written an app. But i cant solve my problem.
I have an AlarmManager to push Notification. And now I want to have a button on my Notification. when I click that button, my app will run a function in service ( post request to thingspeak ) but i have tried many ways but i cant solve it. Help me plz!
I have 4 classes: Activiti, Alarm_reciever, HttpRequest and RingtonePlayingService.
here is my code to push notification.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID) {
    Log.e("start", "startingcommand" + startID + ": " + intent);
    long[] v = {500, 3000};

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);

    Notification mNotify  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Smart Mini Garden Alarm")
            .setContentText("Click để kiểm tra và tưới cây !!! ")
            .setTicker("Đã tới giờ tưới !!")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconchuan_72)
            .setVibrate(v)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
    NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

I want to have a addAction ( button in notification bar )
And here is my httpRequest i want to run when i click On button in notification

```
public void postData() {
    String fullUrl =  "https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=RICJCNNCNMDURNDS&field1=1"
    HttpRequest mReq = new HttpRequest();
    String data = "";
    String response = mReq.sendPost(fullUrl,data);
```

What i can do next to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **eventbus** to notify your service when you click your button fire event will receive by your service. onEvent receive call your service function [Eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: can you show more for me :( I am so poor in android studio

Comment: @Nth2294 Please integrate event bus with your project

Comment: i added eventbus.java in my project, what i must do next, please explain for me :(

Comment: now Create one class public class BusinessConnectBus
{
    private static EventBus instance = null;

    private BusinessConnectBus()
    {
        instance = new EventBus();
    }

    public static EventBus getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new EventBus();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

Comment: on button click write this code  EventBus bus = BusinessConnectBus.getInstance();
                                bus.post(new MessageEvent());

Comment: register your bus in service when it create like this : BusinessConnectBus.getInstance().register(this);

Comment: add this method in service @Subscribe
 public void onEvent(MessageEvent event){
  //Call Your Method From here
 }

Comment: @Nth2294 Add eventbus library in your project not eventbus.java

Comment: thank for your help, but i have been having many problems with my grande when i create httpRequest.java for my project. So I must use someone's project, which can run httpRequest.java, and fixed it  :( I cant understand about grande :( Do u have another way for me :(

Comment: @Nth2294 no man but my solution will solve your problem of calling service method.

Comment: @Nth2294 if you are satisfy with my answer please accept it so other can get help from it

Comment: Sincerely thanks, but i must continuously find other solution :(